# C# Data Table Type problem on importing from CSV

Tags: c#, import, datatable

I am using the following

```
string sql = @"SELECT * FROM [" + fileName + "]";

using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(
                  @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathOnly +
                  ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=" + header + "\""))
using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    dataTable.Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    adapter.Fill(dataTable);

    intCurrentTableRowCount = dataTable.Rows.Count;

    return dataTable;
}
```

The problem is the 12,13,14 columns are returned as a date field (which would be no problem but some of dates are European ie 24/12/2021) so those data table fields are blank.

Is there a way around this issue? Not even sure where to start.

Comment: CSV data is as folloes

Comment: CSV data is as follows  (the  blank is the one with the date of 21/12/2021) all others are ok  `A,B,C,D,E,f,F,H,I ,J,K,L,M,N,O,P
1401788185-test1a1,Loc 1,s1,1600000,0045-0981,,Loc 1,,1401788185,Type 1,0,103448,21/12/2021,8/5/2021,8/16/2021,146.2
1401788185-test1a2,Loc 2,s2,1680002,0045-0982,,Loc 2,,1401788185,type 1,0,103745,7/28/2021,8/5/2021,8/16/2021,145.7
1401788185-test1a3,Loc 2,s3,1680019,0045-0983,,Loc 2,,1401788185,type 4,0,0,7/23/2021,8/13/2021,8/16/2021,99.8
1401788185-test1a4,Loc 4,s4,1680036,0045-0984,,Loc 4,,1401788185,Type 5,0,0,7/23/2021,8/13/2021,8/16/2021,98.8`

Comment: I'd suggest using managed libraries like [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/) if you can. In my experience it's faster, more convenient and reliable

Comment: CSV Helper did the job. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You cast your column in `varchar`.
If you need datetime in your code, after `import` you can add new column in the dataset and in a loop use `Datetime.TryParse` for parse the date.

Is not the most performant solution but it s will works.

Comment: When you say, cast my column as a varchar are you meaning in the Select statement in place of select *, select a as varcharr........

Comment: Yes it was the idea, but after research on Google, it maybe not work with JET PROVIDER.

Try to add this `;IMEX=1;HDR=NO;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\"";` in connectionStrings. All your columns will be text and the first line will contains header (to remove).
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9409250/8956476