# Format all excel column to General before filling to datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Is it possible to change all the columns of an excel sheet to General type before filling to a dataset? I cannot use Interop or any other 3rd party dll in my application. I'm using OleDbDataAdapter  to fill the data to a dataset.

```
string SourceConstr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + fileName + "';Extended Properties= 'Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=General'";
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(SourceConstr);
string query = "Select * from [Sheet1$A9:FG100]";
OleDbDataAdapter data = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con);
data.Fill(ds);
```

Comment: I assume you mean you want to read every column as a string (varchar) type, right?

Comment: yep, string or General type will do. Any idea lc?

Comment: This is a good question. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567673/how-to-force-ado-net-to-use-only-the-system-string-datatype-in-the-readers-table

Comment: Thanks for the quick response lc, but i have tried ExcelDataReader before, but its not working in my case. My excel file contains currency values like '234567.234653457', and i'm losing all except 4 precision after filling to a dataset.  But if i change all the coluns in the excel to General type full precision is returning. any remedy?

Comment: @All, Finally i'm using interop, no other go it seems.... :(

Comment: Yeah, I'm interested in this answer too. It's a shame if interop is the only way to go here.

Answer (score -1):

one way is get all column and change them with

```
foreach (DataColumn c in DT.Columns)
{
    iColumnCount++;
    if(iRowCount == 0)
        Worksheet.Cells[1, iColumnCount] = c.ColumnName;
    else
        Worksheet.Cells[iRowCount, iColumnCount] = c.ColumnName;

    Worksheet.Columns.AutoFit(); //Correct the width of the columns
    //THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO COLOR THE HEADERS
}


    foreach (DataRow r in DT.Rows)
    {
        iRowCount++;
        iColumnCount = 0;
        foreach (DataColumn c in DT.Columns)
        {
            iColumnCount++;
            if(iRowCount == 1)
                Worksheet.Cells[iRowCount + 1, iColumnCount] = r[c.ColumnName].ToString();
            else
                Worksheet.Cells[iRowCount, iColumnCount] = r[c.ColumnName].ToString();

            Worksheet.Columns.AutoFit(); //Correct the width of the columns
        }
    }
```

chaange color or ant property

```
Worksheet.Range["A1","G1"].Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbDarkBlue;
```

Worksheet.Range["A1","G1"].name or header  = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbWhite;